# asp.net forms authentication deny any user from accessing new web forms

Tags: forms, authentication, web-config

I'm having problem with an assignment on asp.net. I would like to ask, is there any way in which i can prevent any users (including authenticated users) from accessing newly created web forms unless I specified the access rights to the page in the web config?

i tried using

```
<deny users="*">
```

but it denies all users from accessing any pages, even those which i have already specified access rights, for example:

```
<location path="home.aspx">
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good article to  look at, the example is on [MS Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871)

```
  <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <authentication mode="Forms" >
                <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPNETAUTH" protection="None" path="/" timeout="20" >
                </forms>
            </authentication>
    <!-- This section denies access to all files in this 
    application except for those that you have not explicitly 
    specified by using another setting. -->
            <authorization>
                <deny users="?" /> 
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    <!-- This section gives the unauthenticated 
    user access to the ThePageThatUnauthenticatedUsersCanVisit.aspx 
    page only. It is located in the same folder 
    as this configuration file. -->
            <location path="ThePageThatUnauthenticatedUsersCanVisit.aspx">
            <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users ="*" />
            </authorization>
            </system.web>
            </location>
    <!-- This section gives the unauthenticated 
    user access to all of the files that are stored 
    in the TheDirectoryThatUnauthenticatedUsersCanVisit folder.  -->
            <location path="TheDirectoryThatUnauthenticatedUsersCanVisit">
            <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users ="*" />
            </authorization>
            </system.web>
            </location>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: sorry, i dun quite get the codes here, my pages are not inside folders, so i can't specify the folder name in the location path.. i think my question is a bit ambiguous, my objective is to deny all access to new forms except those that i have specified in the web.config settings.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
<location path="FolderName/pagename.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

Comment: hi, answer requires me to already know the page to be excluded access to, but my objective is to deny all access to new forms except those that i have specified in the web.config settings.

Comment: you just have to provide the path of the page that u want to deny access to in the location path

Comment: but the problem is i want it to be applied to all new pages, i have to know the pagename before i can use your method.. so there isn't anyway to do that?